# How to get LWUIT bitmap font?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-resource-editor

I want bitmap font for Form from LWUIT component. I create rs file with bitmap font(that is theme file create by Resource Editor.jar). Then I load that file from my MIDlet with following code...
Then I get Font by, get method("Font 1");  // Font 1 is font name create with LWUIT Editor.

But when i want font from Font object(that from Resource Object) from following code..
Then i get character set from font is ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789.,;:!/*()[]{}|#$%^&<>?'"+- "

What's the problem is that? I change many font type but all are return that String.

Answer (score 0):

The string you are listing above is the charset string which indicates the characters supported by the font it is not the font itself. To apply the font use the `setFont` method of the `Graphics` or `Style` classes.